# Can caer mean "fall" as in "fall for" someone (emotionally) like in English?

Tags: vocabulario

In English one might say "I have fallen for you". Could this be said in Spanish with caer, e.g. "tu me has caido muy bien"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, although the meaning of the sentence you have isn't terribly far off from what you want to say, either, so you would probably not get a correction.

When you say that someone *te cae bien*, you're saying that you find them affable, a good person, etc.  If they *te cae mal*, that means you find them to not be very good natured.  (in general, *caer bien* is a much better translation of the English *like* in the sense of *I like [someone]*, as *gustar* has connotations of non-platonic interest when used with people)

*To fall for someone*, in the sense of crushing on someone or being head-over-heels in love with them, the most common way is to use **enamorarse**: *Me he enamorado de ti*, often with an intensifier like *perdidamente* or more colloquially (in Spain, at least) *hasta las trancas* or *hasta los huesos*.

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to know whether that was a a platonic phrase or not. And by the way it's "having a crush on someone", not "crushing on someone". And "heels" not "heals". Thanks.

Comment: You're corret about heals, but *crush* works either way.  In my dialect (SAE), we use it quite often.

Comment: What is SAE, is that a dialect?

Comment: @aradnix Indeed. SAE is Southern American English.